# Task for printing table of numbers (patterns)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

The task is to print this table of digits. I am a total beginner. How can I approach it, and are there any "lifehacks" for doing that kind of pattern? Right below I have attached my code - but this one is not what I need.

```
0
1 0 9
2 1 0 9 8
3 2 1 0 9 8 7
4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6
```

Code:

```
for start in range(10,14):
  for i in range(start,6,-1):
    print(i%10, end='')
print()
```

Comment: What *is* what you need?

Comment: i need to print the table of numbers i have mentioned above

Comment: These types of problems are about recognizing patterns. What patterns can you identify going on in this table of numbers?

Comment: Is the code you have provided an attempt at the problem, or is that just a random piece of code? If it is an attempt what does it (not) do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the pattern.

In each row the starting number is increased by 1. In each column the numbers are decreased by 1 and then modulo 10 is applied. The number of columns can be calculated from the row number.

```
for row in range(5):
    for col in range(row * 2 + 1):
        print((row - col) % 10, end = ' ')
    print()
```

---

The code is flexible enough to support an arbitrary number of rows. Running the code with `for row in range(12):` will give you the following result

```
0 
1 0 9 
2 1 0 9 8 
3 2 1 0 9 8 7 
4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 
5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 
6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9
```

Comment: thank you so much!....any tips for the best understanding of the patterns?

Comment: Just logic. I looked at the rows: the starting number increased. I looked at the columns: the length corresponded with the row number and the numbers decreased - well kind of decreased, obviously only 1 digit was used. Then I started to write the script. Outer loop was easy, then I had to calculate the number of inner loops. After I did that I had to find the formula for the value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
print(0)
for row in range(1, 10):
    for i in range(row, 0-1, -1):
        print(i, end=' ')
    for i in range(1, row+1):
        print(10-i, end=' ')
    print()
```

As for lifehacks - you need to try and master easier problems first. Try these [questions](https://aviadr1.github.io/learn-python/03_flow_control/exercise/questions.html) or these [questions](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-conditional-statements-and-loop-exercises.php)

And for writing the shortest code using some advanced tricks:

```
print(0)
for row in range(1, 10):
    print(*range(row, 0, -1), end=' ')
    print(0, end=' ')
    print(*range(10-1, 10-row-1, -1), end=' ')
    print()
```